# Different color in sculpt mode - Is this a different material?

Tags: sculpt-mode

[image]

Why is this body showing two colors only in sculpting mode? and isn't in the layout mode.
And how to join them? (I already join those two objects in layout mode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is something called `Face sets`. You can change them in one color by pressing `W` on the keyboard and selecting `Face Set from Visible`.

[image]